# BigCommerce: How to create custom filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bigcommerce

I want to allow for checkbox-filtering, such that when a particular checkbox is 'checked', the page will only show the items corresponding to that checkbox property.

Example) I want only products that are 'new', so I check the box for new products.

How can I create this kind of a filter in BigCommerce? I have tried the url-api filter, granted I didnt expect it to do much, but I have at least tried it.

I am hoping for some way to 'hide' all other products if they dont fall under that checkbox's property.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some javascript to do this for you, but the main thing you'd need here is to somehow differentiate between product types.

**Example:** what designates a product as 'new' vs 'old'?

---

I would be happy to help you write this script to react to the users interaction with checkboxes, but we need some HTMl here for the products themselves in order to have our javascript recognize them.

Can you update your question with some HTML examples of the products or items you want to hide/show based on user interaction with a checkbox selector?